# Cómo acceder a un método de un componente angular desde jquery

Tags: jquery, angular

Estoy capturando unos eventos con jquery en un componente de angular, pero no logro acceder a funciones ni variables de ese componente.

Por ejemplo:

```js
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'cliente',
  templateUrl: './cliente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cliente.component.css']
})

...
export class ClienteComponent implements OnInit { 
  ngOnInit() {
    $('#divHolaMundo').click(function () {
    // Cómo se llama a un método del componente desde aquí?
    this.metodoDelComponente(); // Esto da error, el this es de jquery
  });

  metodoDelComponente() {
    console.log("metodoDelComponente");
  }
}
```

Cómo se debería hacer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divHolaMundo" (click)="metodoDelComponente()">algun contenido random</div>
```

Remueve el código del Jquery del ngOnInit(), no lo necesitas.
Te recomiendo esta lectura del manejo de eventos con Angular [Manejo de eventos](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events)

Comment: Era un ejemplo de evento de jquery, en realidad lo que estoy mirando con jquery es cuando se abre un modal de bootstrap